# How to move local directories to Alibaba Cloud OSS using ossutil tool?

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I want to move a local directory to Alibaba Cloud OSS bucket using ossutil tool. The command I used to upload the **video directory** to **OSS bucket - testbucket** is `ossutil cp -r video oss://testbucket` but it throws `no such keyword` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List OSS buckets using `ossutil ls`.

Once the buckets are listed copy the folder using the following command.

```
ossutil cp -r folder_name/ oss://bucket-name
```

It works on macOS.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i have used this command to upload all my local javascript files to alibaba OSS-

```
ossutil cp -r ~/Documents/personal/store/dist/ oss://cp-web-data/newApp
```